# Rails ActiveRecord eager_load with INNER JOIN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In a large Rails app, I've noticed that we have a piece of code that produces a big `ActiveRecord::Relation`. It uses custom SQL snippets in `.joins()` calls—something like this:

```
def foos
  Foo.
    joins("INNER JOIN bars ON foos.bar_id = bars.id").
    joins("INNER JOIN baz ON bars.baz_id = baz.id").
    where(<some condition on bars>)
end
```

(Note that the `JOIN`s are more complicated than as shown in this example; otherwise I'd obviously just do `Foo.joins(bar: :baz)`.) Now, in some of the places that `ActiveRecord::Relation` is used, that's fine. In others though, we want to have the `bars` association eager-loaded on the `Foo` result set.

Is there any way to do something like this:

```
def scope_with_bars_eager_loaded
  foos.eager_load(:bars, using_existing_join_in_query: true)
end
```

The closest thing I can come up with is:

```
def array_with_bars_eager_loaded
  foos.pluck(<fields we need>).map do |fields|
    bar = Bar.new(<get bar data from fields>)

    # This of course doesn't behave as well as a Foo
    # that we've loaded normally in regards to callbacks,
    # fields we didn't SELECT, etc. But it's probably
    # fine enough for this use-case (we're using this
    # data to render a page).
    Foo.new(<get foo data from fields>, bar: bar)
  end
end
```

Which is a lot more complicated, and also doesn't give us the benefits of being an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Any help here would be appreciated!

--

Note:

Any suggestions that avoid Rails' default behavior of "load every column in the database, sometimes multiple times in one query" are particularly appreciated (that's why I used `.pluck` instead of `.select`, as `.select` constructs queries that load everything in `Foo` even when you explicitly tell it not to). Example: `Foo.includes(:bar).where(bars: { condition: true }).select(:id)` selects every column in `foos`, and selects `foos.id` *twice*.

Comment: I depends somewhat on how you are using it. If you do `Foo.new(hash_of_stuff_i_plucked_from_the_db)` the record is going to behave like a new record and not one fetched from the DB. This will give unexpected behavior when it comes to callbacks and what happens when you pass it to a form for example.

Comment: The code `joins("INNER JOIN bars ON foos.bar_id = bars.id")` is just strange as well since `.joins` creates a `LEFT INNER JOIN` and you could just have written it as `.joins(:bars)`. The major difference between `.joins` and `.eager_load` is that `.joins` uses `INNER` and `.eager_load` `OUTER`.

Comment: Also the difference between `.select` and `.pluck` is that select returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` and `.pluck` returns an array (of arrays). You can use `.select`  to tell AR exactly what columns to pluck. `@foo = Foo.select('foos.id, foos.baz, bars.id, bars.baz').joins(:bars)` for example would only load the columns named.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @max. I'm aware of the things you mention and added some clarifications to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I ended up restructuring my `foos` method so that it could simply perform the `includes` there. Still not super happy with all of the fields being `SELECT`ed, but I guess that's what you get for using `ActiveRecord` instead of something like `Sequel`.